# How can I guarantee that websocket onopen to be called

Tags: javascript, websocket

I use `WebSocket` in `javascript`. `WebSocket` requires the url as constructor parameter and immediately try to connect. I can set `onopen` method only after construct it.

So, if `WebSocket` already establishes the connection before I set `onopen`, then I miss `onopen` event!

How can I avoid this?

To simulate it:

A)

1) In Chrome, open [websocket](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html).
2) Press F12 to open Developer Tools.
3) Open Console
4) Copy and paste all of these codes at once! Enter!

```
uri = "ws://echo.websocket.org?encoding=text";
websocket = new WebSocket(uri);
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { console.log('EHE')};
```

B)

Repeat 1-2-3

4) Copy and paste these codes and run

```
uri = "ws://echo.websocket.org?encoding=text";
websocket = new WebSocket(uri);
```

5) Wait a second

6) Run this code:

```
websocket.onopen = function(evt) { console.log('EHE')};
```

**Result:**

In A) onopen is called. In B) we missed it!

Comment: This can't happen in real code. Running them one line at a time in the developer console works different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of the single-threaded event driven nature of Javascript, what you describe will not happen in real code.  The "open" event can't be triggered until after your current section of Javascript finishes.  Thus, you will always be able to set your `onopen` event handler before the event occurs.

Inserting artificial pauses in the debugger or in the console is an artificial situation that does not occur in real code.

What happens in real code is this:

1. You call `new WebSocket(uri)`
2. The webSocket intrastructure initiates a webSocket connection (an asynchronous operation)
3. The webSocket constructor returns immediately before that connection has completed.
4. The rest of your code runs (including assigning the `.onopen` property and setting up your event handler.
5. The Javascript interpreter is done running your code and returns back to the event loop.
6. If, by now, the webSocket has connected, then there will be an `open` event in the event queue and Javascript will trigger that event, resulting in your `.onopen` handler getting called.
7. If the `open` event has not yet completed, Javascript will wait for the next event to be inserted into the event queue and will run it, repeating that process over and over.  Eventually one of these events will be your `open` event.

The key to this is that `.onopen` is called via an asynchronous event.  Thus, it has to go through the Javascript event queue.  And, no events from the event queue can be run until after your current section of Javascript finishes and returns back to the interpreter.  That's how the "event-driven" nature of Javascript works.  So, because of that architecture, you cannot miss the `onopen` event as long as you install your `.onopen` handler in the same section of Javascript that calls the constructor.

---

If it provides you any comfort, there are dozens of APIs in node.js that all rely on this same concept.  For example when you create a file stream with `fs.createReadStream(filename)`, you have to create the stream, then add event handlers (one of those event handlers is for an `open` event).  The same logic applies there.  Because of the event-driven nature of Javascript, there is no race condition.  The `open` event or the `error` event cannot be triggered before the rest of your Javascript runs so you always have an opportunity to get your event handlers installed before they could get called.

In cases where errors could be detected synchronously (like a bad filename or bad uri) and could trigger an `error` event immediately, then code using something like `setImmediate(function() { /* send error event here*/ })` to make sure the error event is not triggered until after your code has a chance to install your event handlers.

Comment: I'm comforted a little, but for me, *real code* can start with experimentation in the console, and gradually evolve into a final version stored on a server. I don't like being forced to write code that won't work when single-stepped. It feels like cheating.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley -  Single-stepping does not give you realistic timing for asynchronous operations.  It just doesn't.  That's because the real world asynchronous operations don't just "freeze" when you're between steps.  They continue running and completing while you have your Javascript frozen at a step and unable to participate in what's happening.  That's just an artificial situation that is very different in some respects from how real running code works.